# How to make gridview last column Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to make gridview last column fields Button.

Trying but could not do this.

It is possible while adding column in gridview using sql data source. But to do this using this binding method.

Here is my code-

```
 private void BindUserRoles()
    {
        gvUserRoles.DataSource = UserRoles.GetAllRoles();
        gvUserRoles.DataBind();
    }
public List<UserRoles> GetAllRoles()
    {
        try
        {
            List<UserRoles> userRoles = new List<UserRoles>();

            using (IDataAccess dataAccess = Mspl.MobileTracking.DataAccess.DataAccess.GetDataAccess("TrackingConnectionString"))
            {
                var dataReader = dataAccess.RetrieveData("GetAllRoles", null);

                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    UserRoles roles = new UserRoles();
                    roles.RoleId = dataReader["RoleId"].ToString();
                    roles.RoleName = dataReader["RoleName"].ToString();

                    userRoles.Add(roles);
                }
            }

            return userRoles;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return null;
        }

    }



<asp:GridView ID="gvUserRoles" runat="server" EnableModelValidation="True" 
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Yes it is possible, please show UI code, are you adding columns from code behind or from UI itself?

Comment: @Iti- adding from code behind, not from UI

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418379/how-do-i-programmatically-add-a-button-to-a-gridview-and-assign-it-to-a-specific And there is one more link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397856/add-aspbutton-from-codebehind

Comment: Or maybe this is also helpfull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398555/how-to-add-controlls-linkbuttons-on-runtime-into-a-gridview-templatefield

Comment: Please try below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971035/add-boundfield-to-gridview-in-codebehind-file-c-sharp and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13461/how-to-create-columns-dynamically-in-a-grid-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `AutoGeneratedColumn=false` and add templatefields like shown below.

Change your grid code like this-

```
<Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RoleId" HeaderText="RoleId" ItemStyle-CssClass="HideColumn" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Role Name" HeaderStyle-CssClass="normalText">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblRoleName" CssClass="normalText" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RoleName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnEditRole" runat="server" Text="Edit" OnClick="EditRoles_Click"></asp:Button>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your current "last" column with a `ButtonField`, for example:

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="button" CommandName="MoreDetail" 
         HeaderText="More Details" Text="More Details" />
```

Comment: I am not adding from UI. I am adding from code behind

Comment: Instead of adding the button, just hide it by default and if needed, make it visible from your code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below link

[add boundField to gridview in codebehind file C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971035/add-boundfield-to-gridview-in-codebehind-file-c-sharp)

Code project link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13461/how-to-create-columns-dynamically-in-a-grid-view